# radio button value for add

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, ajax

Can anyone say if this code is right or wrong?

```
If(isset($_POST) && ($_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’] == ‘1’))
{
    $totalAmount = $_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’]; //Total amount
    $checkbox_id = $_POST[‘VALUE’]; // The radio button value 

    /* Here get the amount values (3,5.5 or 10) from 

    Database based on the $checkbox_id and store it in

    $amount variable*/


    $total_amount = $amount + $totalAmount;


    Echo $total_amount;

}
```

this is for my radio button which has seperate value when i clicks any one button it will be add with that previous value

javascript

Javascript function

```
Function getPaymentVal()
{

Var checkboxVal = ‘’;

checkboxVal = $("input[@name=’rmr’]:checked").val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: "GET_PAYMENT=1&VALUE=”+ checkboxVal,
   success: function(total_amount)
   {
    //Assigning the final value to the hidden value here
    $(‘#totalamount’).val(total_amount);  

    //Here changing the display of total amount
    $(‘#repair_total_amount’).html(“Total <span class="repair-finalamount-txt">&pound;&nbsp;”+ total_amount+”</span>”);

   }
 });

}
```

Comment: This looks ok, except I think you would normally use `data: {GET_PAYMENT: 1, VALUE: checkboxVal}`. Also, those msword-type quotes may act up. What is the output you're getting?

Comment: agree. pretty sure ‘ and ’ will mess up your code. you must use ' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, I think it's possible because of the `"` and `'` characters which is pasted poorly from another different-character-encoding source. You should type it again to see if the errors happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copy pasted this code from another source and the quotation marks are messed up. Use this instead

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: "GET_PAYMENT=1&VALUE="+ checkboxVal,
   success: function(total_amount)
   {
    //Assigning the final value to the hidden value here
    $('#totalamount').val(total_amount);  

    //Here changing the display of total amount
    $('#repair_total_amount').html("Total <span class='repair-finalamount-txt'>&pound;&nbsp;"+ total_amount+"</span>");

   }
 });
```