# how to display the amount values in radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

hi am developing my project. how do i call the ajax function for onclick button.

```
If(isset($_POST) && ($_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’] == ‘1’))
{

 $totalAmount = $_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’]; //Total amount
 $checkbox_id = $_POST[‘VALUE’]; // The radio button value 

        /* Here get the amount values (3,5.5 or 10) from 

         Database based on the $checkbox_id and store it in

 $amount variable*/


 $total_amount = $amount + $totalAmount;


 Echo $total_amount;

}


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: "GET_PAYMENT=1&VALUE=”+ checkboxVal,
   success: function(total_amount)
   {
 //Assigning the final value to the hidden value here
 $(‘#totalamount’).val(total_amount);  

 //Here changing the display of total amount
 $(‘#repair_total_amount’).html(“Total <span class="repair-finalamount-txt">&pound;&nbsp;”+ total_amount+”</span>”);

   }
 });

}
```

im confusing with this: `data: "GET_PAYMENT=1&VALUE=”+ checkboxVal`, which action i have to give.this is for when i clicks that radio button it will be add awith addcart.

can any one

Comment: This looks very familiar. Is that you magna? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537799/radio-button-value-for-add

Comment: @Spiny Norman, no.... Certainly just cosmic coincidence ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: {GET_PAYMENT: 1, VALUE: checkboxVal},
   success: function(total_amount)
   {
 //Assigning the final value to the hidden value here
 $(‘#totalamount’).val(total_amount);  

 //Here changing the display of total amount
 $(‘#repair_total_amount’).html(“Total <span class="repair-finalamount-txt">&pound;&nbsp;”+ total_amount+”</span>”);

   }
 });
```

EDIT:

Ok, wait. I think what's really going wrong here is that you're adding the value of `GET_PAYMENT`, which is always 1, to the `$total_amount`. Try: `$total_amount = $amount + $checkbox_id;`, or better yet:

```
$selected_amount = (int) $_POST['VALUE'];
$total_amount = $amount + $selected_amount;
```

Comment: The `ajax` method accepts data as a query string as well as a JSON object. Only thing that maybe should be taken into consideration is that the value is properly encoded.

Comment: I like this answer. It might be nice to see the HTML as well as where mercylouis (or should I say magna?) assigns the value for checkboxVal. +1

Comment: I think his problem is in binding this to the click event, anyways I don't think you should answer this kind of spammer!!

Comment: @maus Ah, ok. It was kind of a shot in the dark :) Thanks.

Comment: @Amjad I'm sure he'll learn. At least he's asking about programming, right? (edit: or she, of course)

Comment: @magna You're very welcome and I appreciate it, but I think everyone would appreciate it even more if you went to all your previous questions and accepted some answers (click the accept link next to the answer that helped you most). If there's no answer that helped you solve your problem, read the answers and the comments to find out why people don't understand your problem and edit your question to clarify what your problem is. Also, if you find out more about your problem yourself, write about it! People have spent time looking into it and will probably want to know what worked for you.